# getting data for d3.js from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, d3.js

I'm really new to d3.js and not an expert in javascript. But for my bachelor thesis I need to fetch some data from a mysql database and convert the result to json.
Now i'm at a point where i stuck. I try to use [this Tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html) and it works kind of... but i've got trouble with the data when i try to connect it to d3.

my php file looks like

```
<?php 
    define("IN_MYBB", 1);
    require("global.php");
    $get_relation = $db->query("SELECT r_id,r_from,r_to,r_kategorie as kom FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "relas WHERE r_npc = 0 LIMIT 10");
    $relas= array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_relation))
        {
            $relas[] = $row;
        } 
        header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
        echo json_encode($relas);
?>
```

(I'm using some functions from mybb.com to get the data, because i use data from a forum)
My Output from that php looks pretty fine. (i think)

```
[{"r_id":"7","r_from":"17","r_to":"1","kom":"Bekannte"},{"r_id":"8","r_from":"1","r_to":"17","kom":"Bekannte"},{"r_id":"9","r_from":"422","r_to":"448","kom":"Familie"},{"r_id":"10","r_from":"422","r_to":"382","kom":"Freunde"},{"r_id":"960","r_from":"654","r_to":"581","kom":"Freunde"},{"r_id":"15","r_from":"503","r_to":"504","kom":"Liebe"},{"r_id":"16","r_from":"503","r_to":"511","kom":"Freunde"},{"r_id":"21","r_from":"382","r_to":"422","kom":"Freunde"},{"r_id":"23","r_from":"511","r_to":"503","kom":"Freunde"},{"r_id":"26","r_from":"448","r_to":"422","kom":"Familie"}]
```

now i tried to connect the php file to my d3.js

```
d3.csv("http://localhost:8888/mai20/visual.php").then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(d){
        console.log(d)
    });
});
```

and my output looks really ugly, and i'm pretty sure something is not working. I'm even not able to get in the for each loop...

```
[columns: Array(80)]
columns: Array(80)
0: "[{"r_id":"7""
1: "r_from"
2: "17"
3: "r_to"
4: "1"
5: "kom"
6: "Bekannte"
7: ""
8: "{"r_id":"8""
9: "r_from"
10: "1"
11: "r_to"
12: "17"
13: "kom"
14: "Bekannte"
15: ""
16: "{"r_id":"9""
17: "r_from"
18: "422"
19: "r_to"
20: "448"
21: "kom"
22: "Familie"
23: ""
24: "{"r_id":"10""
25: "r_from"
26: "422"
27: "r_to"
28: "382"
29: "kom"
30: "Freunde"
31: ""
32: "{"r_id":"960""
33: "r_from"
34: "654"
35: "r_to"
36: "581"
37: "kom"
38: "Freunde"
39: ""
40: "{"r_id":"15""
41: "r_from"
42: "503"
43: "r_to"
44: "504"
45: "kom"
46: "Liebe"
47: ""
48: "{"r_id":"16""
49: "r_from"
50: "503"
51: "r_to"
52: "511"
53: "kom"
54: "Freunde"
55: ""
56: "{"r_id":"21""
57: "r_from"
58: "382"
59: "r_to"
60: "422"
61: "kom"
62: "Freunde"
63: ""
64: "{"r_id":"23""
65: "r_from"
66: "511"
67: "r_to"
68: "503"
69: "kom"
70: "Freunde"
71: ""
72: "{"r_id":"26""
73: "r_from"
74: "448"
75: "r_to"
76: "422"
77: "kom"
78: "Familie"
79: "]"
length: 80
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

it seems like it messed up the key and values... and i have no idea, where i am wrong. So perhaps someone her can help me please I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are returning data as a JSON from your script, when loading the data with D3, you need to use [d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#json):

```js
d3.json("http://localhost:8888/mai20/visual.php").then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    data.map(d => console.log(d));
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I swear i have read the code over and over again and didn't see the mistake... of course i should have use json ^^